# CQRS Examples and Screencasts

Tags: c#, design-patterns, frameworks, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm looking for some in depth end-to-end CQRS examples with a reasonable set of unit tests.

Also, if anyone knows of some CQRS screencasts as well it would be extremely handy.

I'm already aware of these examples

- [CQRS Info](http://dddcqrs.com/examples/)
- [Super Simple CQRS](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/31/super-simple-cqrs-example/)

Comment: Recently Vladimir Khorikov @vkhorikov has produced new course in Pluralsight named "Pluralsight CQRS in Practice", he is a professional guys in this field and also DDD.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There's a implementation here [MarkNijhof](https://github.com/MarkNijhof/Fohjin).

But after reading the documents from the CQRS Info site my favourite resource is [Think Before Coding](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/) look at the post Tags. (http://thinkbeforecoding.com/)

Some other useful resources...

- http://distributedpodcast.com/
- http://www.udidahan.com/
- http://abdullin.com/

Comment: New one from Martin Fowler: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

Comment: There is good: http://www.cqrs.nu/

Answer (score 14):

[Microsoft patterns & practices](http://msdn.com/practices) is working on a guidance project called CQRS Journey. The idea is to develop a non-trivial system with multiple bounded contexts and apply CQRS, ES and other patterns & techniques where appropriate and document all lessons learnt along the way. The project is still in flight. Check out the journey progress at http://cqrsjourney.github.com

- Code repo is at https://github.com/mspnp/cqrs-journey-code
- Doc review via http://pundit.cloudapp.net

The project involves many [community members](http://cqrsjourney.github.com/advisors/members/) and accepts contribitions!

Comment: V3 with no downtime migration shipped - http://cqrsjourney.github.com/blog/2012/07/19/V3-Final-Release/

Comment: Final release is out - http://aka.ms/cqrsrelease

Comment: Final release eBook - aka.ms/cqrspdf

Comment: The book is now in print - http://www.amazon.com/Exploring-CQRS-Event-Sourcing-maintainability/dp/1621140164

Answer (score 9):

http://ncqrs.org/

Is a useful resource...

Comment: ncqrs.org appears to be a dead link - so try https://github.com/ncqrs/ncqrs

Answer (score 7):

Here is a complete example I wrote for [my CQRS lib Scritchy](http://github.com/ToJans/Scritchy):

- [Example.Domain](http://github.com/ToJans/Scritchy/tree/master/Example/Domain): Domain implementation
- [Example.Specs](http://github.com/ToJans/Scritchy/tree/master/Example.Specs) : Domain behavior specs using MSpec
- [Example.Web](http://github.com/ToJans/Scritchy/tree/master/Example.Web) : Example MVC web app (demo at http://scritchyExample.apphb.com )
- [Example.SignalR](http://github.com/ToJans/Scritchy/tree/master/Example.SignalR) : Example html/Javascript/SignalR web app (using the same domain code)

Creating your CQRS app using [the Scritchy nuget package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Scritchy) is pretty straightforward and [gets you up and running in a few minutes](http://scritchyexample.apphb.com/#quickstart)

Answer (score 6):

Here's some more informational resources, but unfortunately no end-to-end code samples beyond SimpleCQRS and MarkNijhof.

- http://seabites.wordpress.com/
- http://richarddingwall.name/2010/06/15/brownfield-cqrs-part-1-commands/
- http://www.agilification.com/post/CQRS-Series-from-Mark-Nijhof.aspx
- http://jonathan-oliver.blogspot.com/

I have come across a couple other code samples, though I have not yet had time to review them whatsoever:

- http://dddsamplenet.codeplex.com/
- http://agrcqrs.codeplex.com/

Comment: Now there is an end-to-end comprehensive sample from Microsoft patterns & practices at http://aka.ms/cqrs

Answer (score 6):

Udi Dahan would have to be one of the experts in the CQRS field, imo.

Here is a blog about it: http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/

Here is a CQRS podcast (I haven't watched it, but if it's anything like his course presentation it will be great): http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/open-source-dot-net/udi-dahan-command-query-responsibility-segregation/rl-311

Here is a SOA talk (may not be directly relevant but excellent regardless): http://vimeo.com/5022174

If you have the time, I'd recommend popping along to one of Udi's courses when one is nearby, as he covers CQRS in depth.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MichaelLehman/PP-Symposium-2010-The-Commmand-Query-Separation-Pattern-Chris-Tavares) screencast by Chris Tavares. It gives a good overview of CQRS and it shows some good examples in code.

URL:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MichaelLehman/PP-Symposium-2010-The-Commmand-Query-Separation-Pattern-Chris-Tavares

Comment: This screencast is by Chris Tavares.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a sample of just the BDD style of unit-tests, it isn't end-to-end, but since you mentioned unit tests I figured it might be of interest.
http://lucisferre.net/2011/02/05/behavior-driven-test-driven-domain-driven-design/

Answer (score 3):

There was a great session during aspConf 2012 by Ashic Mahtab.

[CQRS with ASP.NET MVC - A Year On](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/CQRS-with-ASP-NET-MVC-A-Year-On)

Complete source code [here](https://github.com/ashic/aspConf-cqrs)